# how to add two transitions on vue js at the same time?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm new on the Vue js framework. And I'm trying to use 2 transition in one element which is working but the second transition doesn't work very well.
I mean the first works with the animation properties but the seconds works but the animation doesn't it.

Here's my code:

```
<div id="app-17" class="col-sm-4">
    <h1>Lista con VueJS - AJAX</h1>
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary mb-4" v-on:click="show = !show">Mostar/Ocultar Lista</button>
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary mb-4" v-on:click="shuffle">Shuffle</button>
    <transition-group name="flip-list" tag="ul">
                <li  v-if="show" v-for="item in list" v-bind:key="item.name">
                        {{item.name}}
                </li>
    </transition-group>

</div>
```

Here's the JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var urlUsers = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users'
        app17 = new Vue({
            el: '#app-17',
            created: function(){
                this.getUsers();
            },
            data: {
                list: [],
                show: false
            },
            methods: {
                getUsers: function () {
                    this.$http.get(urlUsers).then(function (response) {
                        this.list = response.data;
                    });
                },
                shuffle: function () {
                    this.list = _.shuffle(this.list)
                }
            }
        })
    </script>
```

And the CSS style :

```
<style>
        /*ANIMATION APP-8*/

        .fade-enter-active,
        .fade-leave-active {

            transition: opacity .5s;

        }

        .fade-enter,
        .fade-leave-to
        /* .fade-leave-active below version 2.1.8 */

            {
            opacity: 0;

        }

        .flip-list-move {
            transition: transform 1s;
        }
    </style>
```

I'm also using those links:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.14.1/lodash.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue-resource/1.5.1/vue-resource.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Here's live example:
https://codepen.io/blackandnoob/pen/qyeJVW

Comment: i am not able to understand your question well ,but can understand that after shuffle transidion is not working right ?

Comment: @Sphinx. The OP is using `<transition-group>` correctly. Your suggestion is wrong.

Comment: should be change the css selector from `fade` to `flip-list`

Comment: OK guys ,here's a live example:
[link](https://codepen.io/blackandnoob/pen/qyeJVW) 
The transition of Shuffle works with animation , but the other fade is working without animation

Comment: @PaulVH so your question is first button doesn't trigger enter/leave transition?

Comment: yeah , I mean u can click the button and works but the transition of 1sec is not working only works the shuffle transition

Comment: what about [this codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RBXeBo)? For `but the transition of 1sec is not working only works the shuffle transition` , not sure what you mean. Are you talking about `the transition of 1sec` doesn't have opacity transition?